# Use chrome extension to trick page into thinking it's not in an iFrame

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to create a Chrome extension to trick a site loaded in an iFrame into thinking it's not in a frame?

We load clients' sites into an iframe for demos, but some resources get blocked due to them disallowing being loaded in an iFrame. We'd like to load these sites into a frame as though you were browsing directly to the site in  a standalone tab.

Comment: what do you exactly want to achieve? What is the particular problem you want to solve?

Comment: @smnbbrv Elaborated the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Chrome's `webRequest` in order to intercept the server response. See the [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Here you go for `onHeadersReceived` event where you are in control of any response headers => you need to remove `X-Frame-Options` header from the response.

That's pretty much it, if this is the only problem in loading those sites.

However, for the sake of completeness, in order to fully trick the browser (which you most likely **do not need**) you need also to inject a script into every page that would clear up some things like `window.parent` by simple removing them from `window` object and some other things like origin etc. However removing the header would work for 99.9999% of your use cases.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: This works for most things, but does not work for sites like Gmail or Yahoo.com